# Products not visible in Google Shopping?

Tags: magento, google-shopping

I have a magento website which creates a XML for google shopping. The XML is imported and the products are approved in google merchant but none of them are visible in google shopping.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Do I have to pay to get them displayed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a google adwords account and then link the adwords to the merchant account.

then you need to create a google product listing ad campaign.

you can starts here

[google support](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/4637089)

and on the left side you will see more helpful links

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can check again include the product data, feed updates, account status, and Google Shopping policies. If you are still unable to resolve the issue, you can reach out to Google Merchant Center support for assistance.